# Why the Python built-in functions of sum() and min() are much better?

Tags: python, algorithm, sum, min, built-in

Why the built-in functions of sum() and min() are much better than the simple implementation (comment out in the following) ? How do they improve the performance?

```
class Solution(object):
def minMoves(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    '''
    m = sys.maxint
    s = 0
    for i in nums:
        s += i
        if i < m:
            m = i
    '''
    m = min(nums)
    s = sum(nums)
    return s - m * len(nums)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they written in highly-optimized C.

Answer (score 2):

As Tigerhawk mentioned in the comments, most built-in functions were written in C, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Python/clinic/bltinmodule.c.h).  I believe what we're looking for starts at [line 591](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Python/clinic/bltinmodule.c.h#L591):

```
_sum(PyObject *module, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *return_value = NULL;
    PyObject *iterable;
    PyObject *start = NULL;

    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "sum",
        1, 2,
        &iterable, &start)) {
        goto exit;
    }
    return_value = builtin_sum_impl(module, iterable, start);

exit:
    return return_value;
}
```